# cant't get NetBeans to compile Java ME

Tags: java-me, netbeans-7

I've been trying for the past 5 hours to make my java ME application to compile without any luck.

#### System:

W7 64X

NetBeans 7.0

Java JDK 32X

#### Error Message:

> Execution failed with error code 1.

I've done the following things trying to fix it.

Added **runMidlet** to DEP.
turned off my anti-virus/firewall.
reinstalled and rebooted 5 times prolly.

and something I found on google.

```
Please edit <javamesdk_installdir>\toolkit-lib\modules\bootstrap\conf\system.properties and reconfigure the device-manager.object-registry.host=localhost to: device-manager.object-registry.host=127.0.0.1

And one other thing that can be the causes for this issue is the Port 1299 might be taken

Please edit <javamesdk_installdir>\toolkit-lib\modules\bootstrap\conf\system.properties and change
device-manager.object-registry.port=1299 to: device-manager.object-registry.port=1999
```

the only thing that has changed since I started is that now I get the error after 10 sec and before it was after 24sec.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: is WTK really necessary? I have 2.5.2 installed.

Comment: Yes you need either WTK or JME SDK 3.0. When you are creating project are you selecting WTK/JME SDK as your project JDK?

Comment: I have both, and when I try to run my app SDK 3.0 shows a notification that its starting but no emulator is displayed on the screen, after 24 sec i get that error.

Comment: OK, try to create simple start-up project that is failing for you, zip it up and attach to the post or provide link where can it be accessed and I will try to find time to have look at it

Comment: The thing is I have this working java ME app that is an example on how to handle collisions that I've downloaded from my universities website, it compiles on the schools PC, but at home it wont show the emulator. So my guess is something has to be wrong with my PC.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I asked you to create me start-up project to see if you know how to configure your project. School examples may be working at school because they use same old software as they did 2-3 ago when notes been writen, and they do not work for you because you have newer environment and possibly do not know how to change your settings

Comment: Oh ok.
here you go [Collision](http://www.fileserve.com/file/wvXs8Ee)

Comment: OK, I downloaded your project and run it. I had no problems at all. My setup Windows 7 64bit, Java 1.6.0_24 32bit, Netbeans 7. Can you tell me what you see under Java Platforms in Tools option?

Comment: ok
I see CDC Java Platform Micro Edition SDK 3.0
J2ME Java Micro Edition SDK 3.0. When I try to refresh it fails after 15 sec maybe. 
J2SE JDK 1.6 default, pathway to a random file `C:\**Program Files (x86)**\NetBeans 7.0\mobility\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\lib\fp_1.1.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mine solved by installing standalone Java ME SDK http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html then in the netbeans go to *Tools > Java Platform* then remove default J2ME Platform, next click *Add Platforms* and locate your new Java ME SDK.

if that still failed try uninstall Java ME Plugin in *Tools > Plugins > Installed* then install **Mobility** in *Available Plugins* Tab

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you added JME SDK 3, but check bellow my setup

[image]

Comment: I've compared my files to yours and they are identical, at least in the javaDoc dir.

Comment: Then my last suggestion is to remove NetBeans, JME(if istlled separately) and JDK 1.6. Then install JDK 1.6 32bit, make sure it is installed in correct directory (DRIVE_NAME:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_VersionNumber). Download and install NetBeans 7 with custom setup (only JavaSE and JavaME). Download fresh copy of school sample code and run it

Comment: Just tried that without any luck :(
But thanks a lot for your help.